# how to rewrite two multiple variable using htaccess and get variable values

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem in my code ..
Basically i want to rewrite an URL like this

`news.com/category/international-news/page/1`

in the above example `category.php` is a page and `international-news` is a category.

I could get only one variable's value using htaccess rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/ category.php?categoryURL=$1
```

I can get category's name value but dont know how to get second variable value which is page
so can somebody tell me that how can I pass two variable at the same time in my url ?

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/ category.php?categoryURL=$1
```

I also tried

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/ category.php?page=$1
```

I want this URL
`news.com/category/international-news/page/1`

and want to get two values from it 
`international-news` and `page` value

Answer (score 0):

you simply capture the parameters you want with parentheses.

```
RewriteRule category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+) category.php?categoryURL=$1&page=$2
```